# Career path: Is going for PMP along with having a rich experience in the InfoSec field a good career move?

Tags: professional-education, certification, career

I think the title pretty says it all.

Do you think that if one has experience in implementations of security and network solutions, and then gets to become a PMP, will that be an added value to his career?

One way I can think of it, is that companies will hire these people from the outside, and would have them planning and running the entire project from A to Z. So it basically gives you the option to be independent.

Any thoughts on the matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A project management certification will help your career if you want to move from a technical to a managerial or project management role. If you want to stay technical then it has no real value, and even makes you look less technical. I have a PMP and I have to say it's not particularly valuable, but it is an important credential to have as an IT management consultant.

Comment: My Ultimate goal is to get into consulting and\or management - I am definitely sure of that. I will approach it in a few years once I get enough experience and expertise in the technical area. Would that be a suitable path?

Comment: A PMP or a Prince2 is a good step then. Prince2 has less of a project management experience requirement and may be a better choice for you.